# Insert line break after every two rows of database

Tags: php

I have a little script that prints a certain amount of rows in a mysql database.

Is there any way to make it so that after every *second* row it prints, there is a line break inserted?

Adding a line break after every row is simple, but I don't know how to add one after every other row. Is that possible?

Comment: Perhaps you could show your code so far?

Comment: Logic would say divide your rownum by 2 if there is no remainder insert a blank row.  I'm not a php expert so no idea on the syntax, but this may give you a general idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add new variable before the loop

```
$i = 0;
```

then in your loop add

```
if ($i != 0 && $i%2 == 0)
   echo '<br/>';
```

Answer (score 4):

You write "script" but in tags you have PHP, so I suppose you need PHP code:

```
foreach ($rows as $row) {
    if ($i++ % 2) { 
         // this code will only run for every even row
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: PHP *is* a *scripting* language.  Technically, all PHP "code" is "script" =)

Answer (score 4):

```
$i=1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query))
{
    //your code
    if ($i % 2 == 0)
        echo '<br>';
    $i++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the language, something like this should do it: (in php) (where $arr is an array of results)

```
$str = '';
$i = 0;

for ($i=0; $i<count( $arr ); $i++)
{
   if ( ( $i + 1 ) % 2 === 0 )
   {
      $str .= $arr[$i] . '<br />';
   }
   else
   {
      $str .= $arr[$i];
   }
}

echo $str;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use php and modulo.

such as

```
if($i % 3)
  {
    echo '<br />'..
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do this inside the query for some reason, you could use something like

```
SELECT
  <your fields>,
  IF (((@rn:=@rn+1) % 3)=0,'<br>','') as brornot
FROM
  <your tables and joins>,
  (@rn:=0)
```